# yadcf use an external button to exclude data

Tags: yadcf

I use exFilterColumn to get pre-selected filters, but now I'm trying to achieve something else.

Basically, I want my external buttons to filter the table in a query like

```
WHERE columnD != columnE AND columnF != 'picky' AND columnG != ''
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform an [exclude](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L180) filering on a column with the `exFilterColumn` api call you should add a `_exclude_` prefix to the query, for example:

```
yadcf.exFilterColumn(oTable, [[3, '_exclude_b_value']]);
```

where the query string itself is *b_value* , the only issue that still need to be fixed in yadcf is to make the exclude checkbox to appear checked in when such `exFilterColumn` is being called